Siunitx uncertainty rounding
The siunitx options round-mode=uncertainty and drop-zero-decimal produces unwanted results if a zero decimal place is dropped. I guess the drop-zero-decimal option should be ignored in the given case.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true, round-mode=uncertainty, drop-zero-decimal=true}

\noindent
\num[round-precision=2]{-52.11(43)}\\
\num[round-precision=1]{-52.11(43)}\\\\           %works 
%       
\noindent
\num[round-precision=2]{-52.01(43)}\\
\num[round-precision=1]{-52.01(43)}\\\\         %does not work
%
\noindent
\num[round-precision=1, drop-zero-decimal=false]{-52.01(43)}\\  %works again

\end{document}

